# Set jQuery Readonly to a timed unlock

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have this form which has two input fields, with a complete checkbox and save button.

Once the checkbox is ticked and the save button clicked, it locks out the input boxes from any futher editing.

This is working correctly.

I want to a add a time onto the read only of the jQuery, say a 10 seconds countdown. Once it reaches the end of the 10 seconds it lets the user edit the form once again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The HTML Code -

`<fieldset>
    <legend>General Information</legend>
    <table class="full-width">
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo form::label('title', 'Summary of Problem') ?></td>
            <td colspan="3">
                <?php echo form::input('title', $test->title, array('class' => 'full-width', 'id' => 'title', 'style' => 'margin-left:2px')) ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo form::label('works_no','Works No.') ?></td>
            <td><?php echo form::input('works_no', $test->works_no, array('id' => 'works_no')) ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>`

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Complete</legend>
<?php echo Form::checkbox('complete', NULL, FALSE, array('id' => 'complete')) ?>
```

```
<div class="columns">
<div class="colx2-left align-center">
    <?php echo Form::button('save-test', 'Save Changes', array('id' => 'save-test', 'type' => 'button', 'value' => 'save-test')) ?>
</div>
```

jQuery Code -

```
$(function()

// Disable form input elements
$('#frm-test :input').attr('readonly', true);
$(document).on('mousedown keydown click', 'select, .datepicker, :radio', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});

// re-enable form elements with exclude class
$('#frm-test .exclude').removeAttr('readonly');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.setTimeout()` javascript method to set ticker to 10 seconds like:

```
window.setTimeout(function() { // fuction to execute after timeout
   $('#frm-test .exclude').removeAttr('readonly');
}, 10000); // timeout time in milliseconds
```